# Обработка html-формы с помощью django

Tags: python, html, django

Имеется примерно такая html-форма:

```
<form action="?" method="post">
  <p><b>Введите ваш текст:</b></p>
  <p><textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="text"> </textarea></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```

Необходимо реализовать простую обработку. Например, пользователь вводит в форму какое-то число. А в ответ ему выводится ответ, где его число, например, возводится в квадрат.
Подскажите, как такое можно реализовать в django?

Comment: в action добавить ссылку на функцию которая будет обрабатывать ввод - [читайте, учите](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указанную задачу можно реализовать в Django, но будет проще реализовать ее в Javascript.

Поскольку пример достаточно простой (возведение в квадрат) вам не надо отправлять данные на сервер и ждать ответа. Такие расчеты можно и нужно провести на клиенте.
Можно воспользоваться библиотекой jQuery чтобы упростить задачу.

При реализации в Django вам надо изучить документацию к формам: [пример реализации view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#the-view) в общих чертах процесс такой:

1. вам надо в `urls.py` обработать маршрут, куда отправляется форма (этот же адрес что и GET запрос или иной).
2. сделать обработчик POST запроса (в Django 2 варианта: функция или класс). Вы можете использовать ту же функцию, что обрабатывает ваш GET запрос, но по другому сценарию `if request.method == 'POST':`
3. проверить форму на валидность (см пример документации). Для этого в `forms.py` опишите вашу форму и типы полей.
4. получить данные из формы `form.cleanned_data['...']` [документация тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data), произвести расчет (возведение в квадрат) и передать рендеру темлпейта эти данные

Comment: Большое спасибо) Всё получилось!